# Python+Tkinter: Redrawing a rectangle in a canvas based on some % value

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have spent an embarassing amount of hours looking for a way to do this... Its for a project I'm working on that has over one hundred canvas items that need to update from a text file. Here is a simple version of that:

**I would like to update a rectangle drawn in a canvas item when I push a button.** I found a real bad hack way to do it that involves a crazy amount of code but I know there has to be some better way.

```
from tkinter import *


class MyGUI:

def __init__(self, root):
    frame = Frame(root)
    frame.pack()

    self.BoxFillPercent = 0 # the canvas items get their % fill from this value

    self.changeButton = Button(frame, text='SB', command=self.changeRange)
    self.changeButton.grid(row=1, column=1)

    self.hAA = Canvas(frame, width=35, height=35, bg='light blue')
    self.hAA.grid(row=2, column=2)
    self.hAA.create_rectangle(0,0,self.BoxFillPercent*35,35, fill="pink")
    self.hAA.create_text(15, 15, anchor='center', text='AA')

def changeRange(self):
    self.BoxFillPercent = 0.5  
    # When I push the button change the fill amount to 0.5
    ? What do I need to add here to make this work ?

root = Tk()
b = MyGUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

**I have tried to use update and update_idletasks among a bunch of other things but I must be missing something.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every item on a canvas has an id. You can use the `itemconfig` method of the canvas to change the item.

```
rect = self.hAA.create_rectangle(...)
...
self.hAA.itemconfig(rect, ...)
```

If you need to apply the same change to multiple objects, you can give those objects a common tag and then use the tag in place of the id:

```
rect1 = self.hAA.create_rectangle(..., tags=("special",))
rect2 = self.hAA.create_rectangle(..., tags=("special",))
...
self.hAA.itemconfigure("special", ...)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, got me back on the right track.
I found that I had to name the rectangle: self.fAA = self.hAA.create_rectangle(...) and then use coords: self.hAA.coords(self.fAA, ...)      ...bookmarked your blog :D